# Hide div if not hidden in next 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This is code for displaying a loader image until the page loads

I have this code:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
   var state = document.readyState
   if (state == 'interactive') {
      $('#until_load').show();
   } else if (state == 'complete') {
     setTimeout(function(){
        $('#until_load').fadeOut();
     },1000);
   }
}
```

I want to automatically hide the div if it is not hidden in next 5 seconds ..
sometimes this fails or any other reason ... any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: well 1000 milliseconds is 1 second

Comment: i know but i want to add a code so that even if the state is interactive for next 5 seconds hide the #until_load div .. or hide it earlier if the state changes .. whichever is earlier..

Comment: There are two methods that you can look up that might be useful for to you achieve your goal that does not require this obscure `onreadystatechange` method.  Please look up `setInterval()` / `clearInterval()` JavaScript methods, as well as the jQuery `is.(':visible')` methods.  If you provide more context in your code, I can produce an example for you.

Comment: have you tried

 `setTimeout($(#until_load).hide(),5000);`.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this? If state is interactive, show loader, and set a timeout which will hide it in 5 seconds, else use your other timeout to hide it in 1 second (or immediately?)

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    var state = document.readyState
    if (state == 'interactive') {
        $('#until_load').show();
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#until_load').fadeOut();
        },5000);
    } 
    else if (state == 'complete') {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#until_load').fadeOut();
        },1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: One caveat here, some weak browsers have a minimum interval time, so I   typically put in a minimum of 50 ms (rather than 0) for a seemingly instantaneous/immediate effect.